# Convert UTC Date Format to Local format in Android

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, utc

**2015-09-10T11:28:08**

This is UTC format. I want to change to my local time zone date time format.

```
        Date myDate;
        String formattedDate="";

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            TimeZone utcZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
            simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(utcZone);
            //myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);


        return formattedDate+"";
```

I have already use above code but not working.

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer:

```
private String getDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date value = null;
    try {
        value = formatter.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mmaa");
    dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    String dt = dateFormatter.format(value);

    return dt;
}
```